# MongoDB - How to $getField from $$this for $reduce

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to move an array stored in `old_field` that looks like this:

```
[{id: "XXX", ...}, {"id": "YYY", ...}, ...]
```

Into `new_field` looking like this:

```
{"XXX": {id: "XXX", ...}, "YYY":, {id: "YYY", ...}, ...}
```

As such, I attempted to do a few iterations of the following:

```
$addFields: {
  new_field: {
    $reduce: {
      input: "$old_field",
      initialValue: {},
      in: {
        {$getField: {field: "id", input: "$$this"}}: "$$this"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All of which failed. Note that doing:

```
$addFields: {
  new_field: {
    $reduce: {
      input: "$old_field",
      initialValue: {},
      in: {
        "1": {$getField: {field: "id", input: "$$this"}}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Returns a `new_field` w/ value `1: {the_correct_id_here}`, so I know that the `$getField` works properly (besides likely using `$$this` in the wrong context).

Why isn't `$getField` working in this context? How would I go about doing this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$addField`

   1.1. `$arrayToObject` - Convert the array result from *1.1.1* to object.

   1.1.1. `$map` - Iterate each element in the `old_field` array and return a new array. Convert each element to an object with `k` and `v` properties.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      new_field: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$old_field",
            in: {
              k: "$$this.id",
              v: "$$this"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yUg5nXx5G5w)